# Service Class Autowire Return Null If I Add @EnableJpaRepositories Annotaion

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, annotations

If I Add @EnableJpaRepositories Annotation in Configuration Class Then Service Class Autowire Instance Become Null And Throw Null Pointer Exception And If I remove Annotation Autowire Works Fine.

I Got NullPointerException In return ajaxDemoService.getCountryList(); Line Of Controller.

How can I Solve This Issue?

Below Is My Configuration Code.

```
 @Configuration
        @EnableWebMvc
        @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.advanced.controller","com.advanced.service","com.advanced.repository"})
        @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.advanced.repository"})
        public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
            @Bean
            public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
                InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
                resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
                resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
                resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
                return resolver;
            }

                @Override
                public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                    registry
                        .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
                }
            }
```

controller.java

```
 @Controller
    public class AjaxController {

        @Autowired
        AjaxDemoService ajaxDemoService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/country", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody  List<Country> getAllCountries() {
            return ajaxDemoService.getCountryList();
        }
    }
```

Service.java

```
public interface AjaxDemoService {

    public List<Country> getCountryList();

    public List<State> getStateList(int countryId) throws Exception;
}
```

ServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class AjaxDemoServiceImpl implements AjaxDemoService {

    @Autowired
    CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    StateRepository stateRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Country> getCountryList() {
        return countryRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<State> getStateList(int countryId) throws Exception {
        return (List<State>) stateRepository.findById(countryId).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Resource Not Found"));
    }
}
```

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` it will lead to a failure on starting the application. Show the class which you blame from having a `null` reference and the code that shows the usage of that service.

Comment: `@Autowired
 AjaxDemoService ajaxDemoService;`

ajaxDemoService instance is null

Comment: As stated an `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` it would prevent the application from starting. If it is `null` you are either creating an instance of the service yourself or due to AOP and a `final` method you have proxy issues. But as satated please show the code and not as comments but as an edit of  your question.